# How to add a URL prefix in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, servlets

I have a Spring Boot 2 app, mainly used for REST endpoints, and I want to add a prefix to endpoints via a bean configuration instead of having a setting in the application.yml file that makes the prefix global. i.e example.com/**api**/ I know that you can have this configured with a annotation on the controller classes as well, but I want to know if this can be done with a bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in the following way:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

@Configuration
public class DispatcherServletCustomConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
        return new DispatcherServlet();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(
                dispatcherServlet(), "/api/");
        servletRegistrationBean.setName(DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DEFAULT_DISPATCHER_SERVLET_REGISTRATION_BEAN_NAME);
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will making a new dispatcherServlet cause any issues?

Comment: None unless you are working on webApplicationContext configurations but it's customizable.